# connect dotCMS cluster to external elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, dotcms

I'm trying to create a cluster of three servers with dotCMS 5.2.6 installed.
They have to interface with a second cluster of 3 elasticsearch nodes.
Despite my attempts to combine them, the best case I've obtained is with both dotCMS and elastic up and running but from dot admin backend (*Control panel* > *Configuration* > *Network*) I always see my three servers with red status due to Index red status.

[image]

I have tested the following combinations:

In ***plugins/com.dotcms.config/conf/dotcms-config-cluster-ext.properties***

```
AUTOWIRE_CLUSTER_TRANSPORT=false
es.path.home=WEB-INF/elasticsearch
```

Using `AUTOWIRE_CLUSTER_TRANSPORT=true` seems not to change the result

In ***plugins/com.dotcms.config/ROOT/dotserver/tomcat-8.5.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch-override.yml***

```
transport.tcp.port: 9301
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: first_es_server:9300, second_es_server:9300, third_es_server:9300
```

Using `transport.tcp.port: 9300` cause dotCMS startup failure with error:

```
ERROR cluster.ClusterFactory - Unable to rewire cluster:Failed to bind to [9300]
Caused by: com.dotmarketing.exception.DotRuntimeException: Failed to bind to [9300]
```

Of course, port 9300 is listening on the three elasticsearch nodes they are configured with transport.tcp.port: 9300 and have no problem to start and create their cluster.

Using `transport.tcp.port: 9301` dotCMS can start and join the elastic cluster but the index status is always red even if the indexation seems to work and nothing is apparently affected.

Using `transport.tcp.port: 9309` (as suggested in the dotCMS online reference) or any other port number lead to the same result as 9301 case but from dot admin backend (Control panel > Configuration > Network) the Index information for each machine still repot 9301 as ES port.

[image]

---

**Main Question**

I would like to know where the ES port can be edited considering my Elasticsearch cluster is performing well (all indices are green) and the elasticsearch-override.yml within dotCMS plugin doesn't affect the default 9301 reported by the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Is the HTTP interface enabled on ES?  If not, I would enable it and see what the cluster health is and what the index health is.  It might be that you need to adjust your expected replicas.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-health.html

and

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html

FWIW, the upcoming version of dotCMS (5.3.0) does not support embedded elasticsearch and requires a vanilla external ES node/custer to connect to.

Comment: Yes, http is enabled on the external ES cluster on port 9200 (not on the dot machines configuration as suggest on their documentation) however the error is on tcp 9300 port. Cluster health is, of course, green. Everything seems to work, my only concerns is dotCMS that report index status (within network panel) red.

Comment: I would look at the index statuses themselves - there has to be one or two in the cluster that have invalidate shards/replicas and can probably be deleted.  What does the index tab look like if you run a content reindex?  Is that green?

Comment: yes both index tab or direct curl call to 9200 report index status all green